# How to use opencv4android speed up

Tags: android, c++, opencv

Now I use the opencv4android, use the method "cv::resize" take too long, about more than 200 millisecond, how can i speed up.

I google for all time, it seem that use "ocl",

but when i use it , it will error when run the application , the exception is follow this：

> 08-11 11:43:07.140: E/cv::error()(18198): OpenCV Error: Unknown error
>   code -6 (OpenCL function is not available: [clGetPlatformIDs]) in
>   void* opencl_check_fn(int), file
>   /hdd2/buildbot/slaves/slave_ardbeg1/50-SDK/opencv/modules/ocl/src/cl_runtime/cl_runtime.cpp,
>   line 83 08-11 11:43:07.140: E/cv::error()(18198): OpenCV Error:
>   Unknown error code -221 (OpenCL not available) in static
>   cv::ocl::ContextImpl* cv::ocl::ContextImpl::getContext(), file
>   /hdd2/buildbot/slaves/slave_ardbeg1/50-SDK/opencv/modules/ocl/src/cl_context.cpp,
>   line 678

please help me

Answer (score 0):

you can use JNI code for more effective efficient result. use this link for more information
https://github.com/joaopedronardari

Comment: thanks Abhishek, but i want to speend up in jni native